# When to call SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Say I have something like this that is called in  `Controller`:

```
using (var context = new SqlContext())
{
    context.Items.Add(new Item("item1"));
}
```

Should I be calling `context.SaveChanges();`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

entity framework implements a unit of work pattern with DbContext this means that you define a package of things you want to do to your database and then call save changes to propogate them all to the database at once. All operations will be executed within a single transaction (for a single saveChanges call) which means that either all or none will be propogated to the database at once.

Before calling save changes, the changes are applied to your local tracking graph but not to the database itself until savechanges is called.

Comment: Will the local tracking graph be persisted after the local `DbContext` is disposed?

Comment: If I don't call `SaveChanges()` before the `DbContext` is disposed, where should I call it?

Comment: no disposing the context will discard any pending changes, the tracking graph only exists for the lifecycle of the context so its deleted when the context is disposed

Comment: @CalebJares calling dispose without calling savechanges will discard all pending changes

Comment: Thanks! That answered everything I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

**yes.**

every change you make won't be saved until `context.SaveChanges();` is called.

Note that if you will have an object from other DbContext (which is absolutly not the situation you gave) you should need to change the entity state explicitly by using these lines of code instead:

```
Item item = new Item("item1")
db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: in general unit of work sugguests that all changes from a users action should occur at once. in most cases this means you shouldnt be spanning instances of DbContext, and if you are .Attach -> make change -> SaveChanges is the sugguested method. The only time I have ever used explicit modification flags is implimenting other data contexts across the top of EF (such as a generic repository)