# Error in calling savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code using Entity Framework:

```
try
{
    using (GameDatabaseEntities context = new GameDatabaseEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<Game> games = context.Games.Where(a => a.isValidGame == false);

        foreach (Game item in games)
        {
            context.Games.Remove(item);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorHandler.ExceptionHandling("Error in `DeleteFalseFlagsDataAccess` method", ex);
}
```

I sometimes get the following error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries.
>
> StackTrace
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>   at Game.DataAccessLayer.DeleteFalseFlagsDataAccess() in C:\Users\Media Depp\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Games\Game\Game

I do not know the reason, should I call `context.SaveChanges()` inside the `foreach`? thanks for helps. I should mention that I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269765/when-to-call-savechanges), and according to the first answer there is no difference, and my code is not wrong. I get confused because I did not find the answer on web. I also have to refer to this point that I get the error in the line which I'm calling the `SaveChanges` instance method.

---

Edit: 
I get the following inner message:

> Message = "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Edit 2:
I have to mention that I am calling this from another thread. but as you see, I am creating the context inside the new thread and I don't think it matters.

Comment: I assume this exception has at least one `.InnerException` that probably explains in greater detail **what** the actual, concrete error is.......

Comment: I agree with you but unfortunately I am using the executable file and it has a built-in error handler that does serialization for errors, it does not support inner exception. I am trying to debug the .exe file in visual studio.

Comment: I think you need to work on `Game` collection's copy because you are modifying games while looping. Try `var games = context.Games.Where(a => a.isValidGame == false).ToList();`

Comment: Definitely doesn't have anything to do with the foreach loop.   I suppose there's another reason concerning your data that's throwing the error.  However; I might suggest also writing the query to remove the items and leave the foreach loop altogether.  Either way, I don't feel like your problem is in the shared code.

Comment: @marc_s I finally found this inner exception after struggling alot: **Message = "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."**

Comment: .ToList() won't change anything, except the query retrieving the data is not done multiple times - this won't happen on SaveChanges() though, but inside the foreach loop. The exception at hand seems to be related to the database connection. where is the database located, what are the DbConnection attributes, which overload of the DbContext-Constructor is used?

Comment: @NikhilVartak I tried `IEnumerable<Game> games = context.Games.Where(a => a.isValidGame == false).ToList();
` but get the same error

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I'm using local database, sql express, and I have used entity frame work

Comment: @medi this does answer my first question, what about the last two?

Comment: because I'm using entity framework it does not really matters. The code works properly and fine but just this thread is not working.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro this is what I have inside my database orm: `        public GameDatabaseEntities()
            : base("name=GameDatabaseEntities")
        {
        }
`

Answer (score 0):

could you use this code instead of context.Games.Remove(item);

```
context.DeleteObject(item);
```

Comment: No because I have to delete from Game list, not from the context